# Eclipse project (or a Java package in a project) displays an error, yet none of the children have errors

Tags: eclipse

[image: An error not reflected among the children]

In Eclipse, I have multiple places where this behavior occurs. As the sample above shows, a project can display an error, yet none of its children have an error. I cannot figure out where the error is that I need to fix. Also, as seen below, within a Java project, there can be an error on a package which, when expanded, has no errors among its children.

[image: A package error not reflected among children]

Comment: Have you looked in project properties? Maybe the project references some resources which are not available.

Comment: Unavailable resources give an exclamation point rather than the red box/white X icon.

Answer (score 0):

t thing I would do is do a **Project > Clean**. don't clean all projects, select the **Clean projects selected below** radio and select your project.

If that doesn't work, then click on the **Markers** tab at the bottom of your screen.
[Markers Tab](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0e082g0db7la3d/2-24-2013%2000-50-44.png)

If your Markers tab is closed. you can use **Window > Show View > Markers**

The markers tab will always show the problem. sometimes, it would be a missing resource, other times it could even be a config file like persistence.xml or faces-config.xml.